# WCF - Return and continue processing

Tags: wcf, task

I have a WCF method.
I would like to return to user a result and continue processing in the server side (via .net Task).
The problem is that I have the "Cannot access a disposed object." error message when I continue processing in the server side.
can anyone help ? how can I implement that. Return a result to user but continue working in the server side.

thanks
Hagai

Answer (score 0):

explore callback contract option for your scenario - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=721